# How to make the “l” key or <right> arrow in vifm move to preview pane instead of opening a file in vim?

Tags: vifm

Currently, when clicking the letter <kbd>l</kbd> or arrow <kbd>→</kbd>, if I am on a directory it moves into it but if I am on a file it opens it in vim. I am wondering if there is a way to change this behaviour for files to move into the "view" pane instead of opening the file in vim.

Comment: Is the "view" pane always on, or do you want to toggle it? Should it be only for files or for directories too? I don't think there is any simple way to make Vifm act differently if the focus is on a directory or in a file.

Comment: Well if this is not possible then maybe something like `-o` in nnn:
`-o      open files only on Enter` (from `nnn -h`)

Because it is really annoying to me to navigate through the folder and then accidentally open a file in vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nnoremap + <s-tab>
nnoremap l :if filetype('.') == "dir"|cd %c|else|exe 'norm +'|endif<CR>
```

The last map overrides <kbd>l</kbd> default behavior. It checks the type of
the selected file. If it is a directory, then `cd` it. Otherwise,
execute the normal mode command <kbd>+</kbd>, that is mapped to <kbd>Shift
-Tab</kbd>, which causes the view pane to be focused (assuming it has already
been activated, of course).

I had to create the first map because I could not get something like `exe 'norm <s-tab>'` to work.